# Duration vs Work...Resource Overallocation Errors

Tags: resource-planning, management

I am fairly new to project so apologies up front...I have several tasks in my project plan which have a set duration; i.e. start and end dates/due dates, but the actual amount of time required for each task is not the entire duration. For example, one task has the duration of 1 day but only requires 1 hour of work. I have set each task to Fixed Duration, input the Work column to calculate hours but still have errors regarding resource overallocation. Logically, these resources are not overallocated because they have not even been assigned more than a few hours of work each day. Like I said I am new to project so I know I'm missing something just not sure what. Any insight or help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Which software are you using; then we can explain to you how to split tasks.

Comment: When you say “I am fairly new to project”, do you mean “Microsoft Project”?

Comment: If you mean Microsoft Project, then yes it is a pain. It makes you specify things that are not important to you.

Answer (score 1):

How many Tasks are there in schedule and what is the calendar defined at project Level. Have you defined any resource calendar ?

can you check in Leveling option, whether it is Day by day, week over week or month over month.
if one resource is defined in project and one Task is defined in Project.

work = 8 hrs ( assume resource is full time).. 4 hrs ( Resource is part time)

another scenario, 2 Tasks are defined and each assigned with Resource X, on first task with resource assignment ( 50%) and other task with resource assignment ( 60%) and Leveling options defined as Day by day, then system will show Resource Overallocation. incase of other settings, overallocation will not come into visibility.